# how to optimize sql server table for faster response?

Tags: sql-server-2005

i found a in a table there are 50 thousands records and it takes one minute when we fetch data from sql server table just by issuing a sql. there are one primary key that means a already a cluster index is there. i just do not understand why it takes one minute. beside index what are the ways out there to optimize a table to get the data faster. in this situation what i need to do for faster response. also tell me how we can write always a optimize sql. please tell me all the steps in detail for optimization.

thanks.

Comment: can you show the sql? how many rows where fetched? how many columns where fetched? do you use the primary key in the sql?

Comment: May be a unused index, can we see the query please ?

Comment: the sql is very simple....that is select * from employee.

Comment: Loading 50000 records in one minute is ok. Do you realy need all 50000 records at a time? I sugest loading less data by applying a filter "where name like 'T%'" and putting an index on that field will solve your problem.

Comment: may be it helps to resove your problem if you update your question and tell us what you want to achive. maybe this is helpful: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to optimize indexes in table is to use SQL Server Tuning Advisor. Take a look http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjT8wL92mqE <-- here

Comment: it does not work if you're trying to optimize a remote database though (because you need specific user rights to do that).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `select * from employee` (as per question comment) then no amount of indexing will help you. It's an "Every column for every row" query: there is no magic for this.

Adding a WHERE won't help usually for `select *` query too.

What you can check is index and statistics maintenance. Do you do any? Here's a [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+server+index+maintenance+best+practice)

Or change how you use the data...

Edit:

Why a WHERE clause usually won't help...

If you add a WHERE that is not the PK..

- you'll still need to scan the table unless you add an index on the searched column
- then you'll need a key/bookmark lookup unless you make it covering
- with SELECT * you need to add all columns to the index to make it covering
- for a many hits, the index will probably be ignored to avoid key/bookmark lookups.

Unless there is a network issue or such, the issue is reading all columns *not* lack of WHERE

If you did `SELECT col13 FROM MyTable` and had an index on `col13`, the index will probably be used.

A `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateCol < '20090101'` with an index on `DateCol` but matched 40% of the table, it will probably be ignored or you'd have expensive key/bookmark lookups

Comment: Adding `where` won't help? That sounds wrong to me.. Reference?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: see my update please. The reference is my things like this http://stackoverflow.com/badges/840/sql-server-2005. Butm, if that isn't enough http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/ + other articles there. Like this http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/index-selection-and-the-query-optimizer/

Answer (score 1):

Select only the columns you need, rather than select *. If your table has some large columns e.g. OLE types or other binary data (maybe used for storing images etc) then you may be transferring vastly more data off disk and over the network than you need.

As others have said, an index is no help to you when you are selecting all rows (no where clause). Using an index would be slower in such cases because of the index read and table lookup for each row, vs full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the merits of returning the whole table to your application that does sound an unexpectedly long time to retrieve just 50000 rows of employee data.

Does your query have an `ORDER BY` or is it literally just `select * from employee`?

What is the definition of the `employee` table? Does it contain any particularly wide columns? Are you storing binary data such as their CVs or employee photo in it?

How are you issuing the SQL and retrieving the results?

What isolation level are your select statements running at (You can use SQL Profiler to check this)

Are you encountering blocking? Does adding `NOLOCK` to the query speed things up dramatically?